# Image of half plane $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z)>\frac{1}{4}\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions

I am wondering how the image of the half plane $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z)>\frac{1}{4}\}$ looks like under the map $f: z\mapsto \sqrt{z}$. The branch of $\sqrt{\cdot }$ is taken such that $\arg(x)=0$ if $x\in (0,\infty)$. Is it possible to describe the image properly?

I know that the image of the plane $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z)>0\}$ is the sector which given in polar coordinates by $\{ (r,\theta) \in \mathbb{C} : \vert \theta \vert<\frac{\pi}{4}\}$. Thus the image of the set $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z)>\frac{1}{4}\}$ is contained in that sector.

Best wishes

Comment: Ok. Can you try to tell me why that is the case? Or is there a picture of the image which shows how messy it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will deal with the branching later

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\Re(z^2) &>& \dfrac14 \\
\Re(r^2e^{2i\theta}) &>& \dfrac14 \\
r^2\cos2\theta &>& \dfrac14 \\
r^2(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta) &>& \dfrac14 \\
(x^2+y^2)\left(\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} - \dfrac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right) &>& \dfrac14 \\
x^2-y^2 &>& \dfrac14 \\
\end{array}$$

Thus, in polar coordinates, the image looks like $r^2 \cos 2\theta > \dfrac14$ and in Cartesian coordinates (Argand diagram), the image looks like $x^2 - y^2 > \dfrac14$.

Plotting gives:
[image]

The **right hand side** is the correct branch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.